# How to describe a proxy object type that always returns a predefined value type?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I currently have the following helper function to create a getter function that always returns result or throws an error:

```
// @flow

type StrictMapType<V> = {
  [key: string]: V
};

const createStrictMap = <V: *>(map: StrictMapType<V>): (name: string) => V => {
  return (name) => {
    if (name in map) {
      return map[name];
    }

    throw new Error();
  };
};

const persons = createStrictMap({
  bar: 'BAR',
  foo: 'FOO'
});

const foo: string = persons('foo');

// This triggers Flow error.
const bar: number = persons('bar');
```

However, I would like to abstract the same logic using proxy object, e.g.

```
// @flow

type StrictMapType<V> = {
  [key: string]: V
};

const createStrictMap = <V: *>(map: StrictMapType<V>) => {
  return new Proxy(
    map,
    {
      get: (subject, name) => {
        if (name in subject) {
          return subject[name];
        }

        throw new Error();
      }
    }
  );
};

const persons = createStrictMap({
  bar: 'BAR',
  foo: 'FOO'
});

const foo: string = persons.foo;

// This triggers Flow error.
const bar: number = persons.bar;
```

How to describe a proxy object type that always returns a predefined value type?

Comment: Is there any reason why you're using `K` for the object keys instead of a `string` (since it's going to have to be a string anyways)?

Comment: @JamesKraus it can be also a symbol

Comment: Ah yeah, never use those. Makes sense.

Comment: FWIW, the Proxy libdef specifies that the property should be a string: `get?: (target: T, property: string, receiver: Proxy<T>) => any;`: https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/82b957dc3414270e5765fa6320a87162aee9aee0/lib/core.js#L766

Comment: For the purposes of this question, lets forget the symbol possibility. If it worked with just string keys, that would suffice of this use case.

Comment: So just drop key type generic parameter and define it as string: `[key: string]: V`

Comment: Done. That doesn't help to answer the question, though. :-)

Comment: [Try](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AZRQE4CWAxigLICGGAKplgDwBqAfKALygDeiooA2gGssaAFygAzoSIA7AOYBdcU0QBfANzISsGVNAkCWSiiz5iZKhg6hm4gFQsAFAFtq4s6QrU62ZiwCUHGw8fIYoAK4EMqAyWPCgAAoEsAAeaI68fKCuGAA0mXwhWXxyWCjijhLhAEYAVlhkuTGUzliB7MEFxaBEkKCOMi04spI19WSBRd1ZYZHRVXUNKPyDrQqa03yqyJugKAAWyfGx8QCiBMkEjv4b3dvF96A3apqI2roooNgEEjoS1gYjCYPBZqI4itVKARxFNmq1xAByABCUIRmVU+T4kFgsBhXVWWERADEcWitmpnm8-rBoFgAHRwOSOb6-XR07GwZ7vX60hmwJksv50yEEG5AA) Am I missing something?

Comment: @AlekseyL. The question is how to describe the actual type, i.e. How to annotate `createStrictMap` return type.

Comment: Reading back the question – it is not clear from the question. Sorry. Will edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the return type as an input type + indexer property:

```
type StrictMap<T> = T & { [key: string]: any };

function createStrictMap<T: *>(map: T): StrictMap<T> {
  return new Proxy(
    map,
    {
      get: (subject, name) => {
        if (name in subject) {
          return subject[name];
        }

        throw new Error();
      }
    }
  );
};

const persons = createStrictMap({
  bar: 1,
  foo: 'FOO'
});

const foo: string = persons.foo;
const bar: number = persons.bar;
const another: number = persons.another;
```